# How to create nested parameters for the requests library

Tags: python, python-requests, query-string

I'm using the popular requests library to request data from an API. The following works:

```
import requests

parameters = {
        'action': 'query_plugins',
        'per_page': 10,
        'browse': 1,
        'page': 1,
}

response = requests.get('https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.1/', parameters)

results = response.json()

print(results)
```

But there are some parameters which are nested, for example, here is a URL I might query:

> https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.1/?action=query_plugins&request[per_page]=10&request[browse]=1&request[page]=1&request[fields][description]=0&request[fields][sections]=0'

In the above case I need to pass the following nested parameters:

```
request[fields][description]
request[fields][sections]
```

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: You can nest dictionaries, have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

If I read [this issue](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2885) correctly, you can simply use the bracketed name as the key for your parameters (see [this comment](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/2885#issuecomment-157327303)):

```
import requests

parameters = {
    'action': 'query_plugins',
    'per_page': 10,
    'browse': 1,
    'page': 1,
    'request[fields][description]': 0,
    'request[fields][sections]': 0
}

response = requests.get('https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.1/', parameters)

results = response.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function to flatten the parameters from a dict of dicts to the key-value pairs in the square-bracketed format the API requires:

```
def params(name, parameters):
    def flatten(d):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                for s, i in flatten(v):
                    yield '[%s]%s' % (k, s), i
            else:
                yield '[%s]' % k, v
    return {name + k: v for k, v in flatten(parameters)}

parameters = {
    'per_page': 10,
    'browse': 1,
    'page': 1,
    'fields': {
        'description': 0,
        'sections': 0
    }
}
response = requests.get(
    'https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.1/',
    {'action': 'query_plugins', **params('request', parameters)}
)
```